# Have 01 Dodge ram 2500 desiel automatic transmission

Tags: automatic-transmission, diesel, dodge, ram

Transmission  started making grinding noise on way home. Took forever change gears put it in my garage dropped transmission found round bearings in bell housing. I can't tell if they were from front pump or torque converter. Having trouble getting front pump out seems stuck. Question being, would it be worth rebuilding or would it be better buy one? A lot of metal in pan. Any suggestions or advice appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You found round, as in ball bearings, in your bell housing? I'm wracking my head, but I don't remember anywhere there could be round bearings up front in the transmission. There's bushings in/around the front, but no bearings that I remember. Strange.

Comment: Well I racked mine too on it but honestly I found 5or 6 round bearings about a  inch long .look a lot like hub assembly bearing.the bell housing is in closed except where started bolts in and access port for touqre bolts.you got me I'd sure like to know if front pump or torque bearings but I just don't no

Comment: Anyone that might no where I can get one for it I sure would appreciate it.everyone I look at would take your retirement fund to get or you could buy 2 good vehicles for what they want bad part it's no joke .

Comment: Negotiate with a couple of shops on the markup over 'trade price'. If you're not planning to wrench it in on your own, then the labor for the install could be a part of the negotiation. Don't buy 'retail' from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

With an Allison?   I work on these everyday.   Just get a rebuilt one from a factory with a  warranty. your chances of it being something 'simple' are around 7%.   anything more is not worth the downtime or failure rate of other parts.